# Не могу перевести число в строку Assembler NASM

Tags: строки, ассемблер, nasm

Не могу перевести число в строку символом ASCII на Assember NASM. То есть 123 -> "1","2","3".Число безззнаковое. Пошел вот таким путем

1. Сначала передавал в подпрограмму параметр - число которое нужно обработать.
2. Далее делил его каждый раз на 1000000, если в частном что-то есть, значить  этот разряд записываем в stack. Предварительно в стеке размещаю 0, и сравниваю с ним на тот случай если кто-то введет 00456 вмето 456. Если в stack-е первым идет число не равное нулю - записываем в stack.
3. Уменьшаем наш делитель на 10. То есть каждый раз уменьшаем разряд и в остатке окажется есть что в разряде или нет. Например 205 - 200/100 = 2 остаток 5. Если делитель (проверка разряда) равно 1, то мы просто записываем остаток в Stack  и переходи к чтению из stack-a.
4. Достаю все из стека, при это ставниваю что вершина stack-a  не была ebp, то есть не дошел ли я до конца при это каждый раз инкрементуруя ecx  чтобы потом знать длину строки. Такой подход избавляет меня от необходимости вести счет сколько чисел я занес в stack.
5. Копирую строку  меняя при этом направление записи. Так как 123  в stack  запишеться как 123, из стека я достану 321 то есть чтение начинаю сначала изменяю добавляя 48, и записываю с конца.

Уже все тыщу раз пересмотрел, вроде все обмозговал, но не работаем код. Я бы не стал задавать вопрос, так как я только учусь и не умею пользоваться отладчиками. Заранее огромное спасибо всем кто откликнеться. Не хочу бросать, вопрос не решенным, как это часто бывает.

Вот сам код:

```
global start_create

section .bss
string resb 7                           ;variable parameter
string2 resb 7

section .data
string2_end equ string2
string2_length dd 0
division10 dd 10                        ;we will add the counter to get a end of string: how many elements we will have after loop


section .text
start_create:   push ebp                ;save the ebp 
                mov ebp, esp            ;get the link to esp. ebp stores just lik of its value
                mov dword [ebp-4], 0    ;set initial value to check if stack has any value
                xor edx, edx            ;edx:eax/ecx ; set 0 in edx because edx:eax will be the divisible
                mov eax, [ebp+8]        ;get the number(parameter) transfered by the calling procedure
                mov ecx, 1000000        ;set the digit to divide - divisor - YOU LATER CAN SET ANY NUMBER

division:       div ecx                 ;get the quotient of the number
                test eax, eax           ;check if the quotient zero
                jnz put_not_zero        ;if it is not so - push the value in stack - otherwise check the first value in stack 
                cmp dword [ebp-4], 0    ;check if initial value on stack is 0, it means we will not put the number in stack
                jnz push_in_stack       ;if first argument is not 0, push 0 in stack 0!+0 12...+0  
                jmp next_digit          ;if the first argument is 0 

put_not_zero:   cmp dword [ebp-4], 0    ;
                jnz push_in_stack
                mov [ebp-4], eax        ;clear the first initial value with normal value

push_in_stack:  push eax                ;save the digit in stack

next_digit:     cmp ecx, 1             ; check if divisor is 10 to finish the loop
                jne continue_division 
                push edx                ;if divisor is 10 we will not continue loop. We will put the remainder in stack 
                jmp read_to_create_string

continue_division:  
                mov ebx, edx            ;move the remainder to ebx to save it
                mov eax, ecx            ;decrement divisor by 10 lower
                xor edx, edx            ;zero the value of the edx, because edx is part of division operation 
                div dword [division10]  
                mov ecx, eax            ;set the new digit divisor
                mov eax, ebx            ;get the remainder for division operation 
                jmp division  

read_to_create_string:
                mov ecx, 0 
read_from_stack: 
                cmp esp, ebp            ;check if we go to a start of the adress of procedure [return adress - 4] = ebp, or we do not have string
                je create_ascii_symbols
                pop edx
                mov [string + ecx], dl  ;write the in string 
                inc ecx                 ;increment ecx to write next number from stack to memory
                jmp read_from_stack

create_ascii_symbols:
                mov [string2_length], ecx ; change value to strore length of taken string to display it later
                add [string2_end], cl    ;string2_end == string2 we add cl instead because we add byte to byte, and in ecx we have not so big number              
                mov esi, string
                mov edi, string2_end
add48_to_ASCII: cld                     ;we do not set value in ecx - counter because we have it afer previously
                lodsb                   ;load number to create ascii symbol
                add eax, 48             ;
                std                     ;change direction to write not 3,2,1 to 1,2,3 . To write from the end
                stosb                   ;
                loop add48_to_ASCII     ;repeat the action several times pointed in ecx - length of the string

                                        ;in string we have string of numbers in ASCII 
display:        mov eax, 4
                mov ebx, 1
                mov ecx, string
                mov edx, string2_length
                int 80h


                mov esp, ebp 
                pop ebp
                ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вы какой-то сюрреалистичный алгоритм описываете. Все же просто:

1. Делим число на 10
2. Остаток с добавлением `30h` (чтобы перевести цифру в символ) в конец строки
3. Если частное равно нулю - выходим
4. Если частное не равно нулю, то используем его как новое число и повторяем итерацию

Входное число в `eax`

```asm
    res resb 10

    mov ecx, 10
    push edi
    mov edi, offset res + 10  ; указатель за концом строки
next_digit:
    dec edi
    xor edx, edx
    div ecx
    add dl, 30h
    mov [edi], dl
    test eax, eax
    jnz next_digit

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eсx, edi  ; указатель на начало строки
    mov edx, edi
    mov edi, offset res + 10  ; указатель за концом строки
    sub edx, edi  ; в edx - длина строки
    pop edi
    int 80h
```